# C# Como agregar un punto luego de dos numero

Tags: c#

quisiera colocar un punto luego de dos numeros:

```
string Num= "200";
string Num2= "32532";


result=2.00 decimal
result2=325.32 decimal
```

Comment: Has pensado en convertirlo a double y dividirlo por 100?

Comment: Así `string num = "2.00";` :) Pero es que falta más detalle, ¿tienes un string con un entero y quieres convertirlo en un tipo decimal (`float`, `double` o `decimal`) asumiendo que los dos últimos dígitos son la parte decimal?

Comment: Si, que los dos ultimo sean decimal de un string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que pasar el numero que tienes como stirng a numerico para poder dividir por 100 y luego aplicar formato `N2` que indica que es un numero de 2 decimales

```
string Num= "200";
string Num2= "32532";

int nroNum = Convert.ToInt32(Num);
Num = (nroNum / 100m).ToString("N2");

int nroNum2 = Convert.ToInt32(Num2);
Num2 = (nroNum2 / 100m).ToString("N2");
```

Para aprender como definir formato

[Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

El `m` detras del 100, esta indicando que se trata de un decimal

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es lo que buscaba.